# Pandas series operations very slow after upgrade

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeing a huge difference in performance between pandas 0.11 and pandas 0.13 on simple series operations.

```
In [7]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)})

In [8]: pandas.__version__                                
Out[8]: '0.13.0'

In [9]: %timeit df['a'].values+df['b'].values
100 loops, best of 3: 4.33 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit df['a']+df['b']                      
10 loops, best of 3: 42.5 ms per loop
```

On version 0.11 however (on the same machine),

```
In [10]: pandas.__version__                               
Out[10]: '0.11.0'

In [11]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)})

In [12]: %timeit df['a'].values+df['b'].valuese
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit df['a']+df['b']     
100 loops, best of 3: 2.3 ms per loop
```

So on 0.13, it's about 20x slower.  Profiling it, I see

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.047 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.047 ops.py:462(wrapper)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.044    0.015 series.py:134(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.044    0.044 series.py:2394(_sanitize_array)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.044    0.044 series.py:2407(_try_cast)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.044    0.044 common.py:1708(_possibly_cast_to_datetime)
        1    0.044    0.044    0.044    0.044 {pandas.lib.infer_dtype}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 ops.py:442(na_op)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 expressions.py:193(evaluate)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 expressions.py:93(_evaluate_numexpr)
```

So it's spending some huge amount of time on _possibly_cash_to_datetime and pandas.lib.infer_dtype.

Is this change expected?  How can I get the old, faster performance back?

Note: It appears that the problem is that the output is of an integer type.  If I make one of the columns a double, it goes back to being fast ...

Comment: I imagine `df.eval('a+b')` will get some of the performance back.

Comment: I have at hundreds / thousands of arithmetic operations w/ pandas dataframes.  I can't switch to eval in every point and in any  case, this was an example -- at other times, they are parts of different frames, etc.

Comment: use 0.13.1 or just released 0.14.0; install bottleneck and Numexpr as well

Comment: Same issue w/ 0.14.0; bottleneck and numexpr are both installed.

Comment: @bsdfish: I think I may have an idea about what's going on.  Does your dtype happen to be `int32`?

Comment: what platform are you on? 32/64 python? what python version? what numpy version?

Comment: Linux 3.9.10, 64 bit python, 1.8.1 numpy.  The dtype seems to be int64; if I make it int32, it's very very fast (964us)! so that's one solution but not a great one ...

Comment: The issue seems to be very tied to int64 in particular, because uint64 is fast too.  There is something specific to _sanitize_array and _possibly_cast_to_datetime going on here.

Comment: fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7342; some very odd thing going on the dtype lookup in cython, not sure why. in any event if you'd like to try out the PR pls do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very odd bug having to do (I think) with a strange lookup going on in cython. For some reason

```
_TYPE_MAP = { np.int64 : 'integer' }
np.int64 in _TYPE_MAP
```

was not evaluating correctly, ONLY for `int64` (but worked just fine for all other dtypes). Its possible the hash of the `np.dtype` object was screwy for some reason. In any event, fixed here: https: github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7342 so we use name hashing instead.

Here's the perf comparison:

master

```
In [1]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)})

In [2]: %timeit df['a'] + df['b']
100 loops, best of 3: 2.49 ms per loop
```

0.14.0

```
In [6]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)})

In [7]: %timeit df['a'] + df['b']
10 loops, best of 3: 35.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm on Window, 64 bit python, np 1.8.1, pandas 0.14.0 and oddly I'm seeing the same performance slowdown with int32 dtypes.
   `In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)})`

`In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
a    int32
b    int32
dtype: object`

`In [5]: %timeit df['a'] + df['b']
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop`

`In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1000000), 'b':np.arange(1000000)}, dtype='int64')`

`In [7]: %timeit df['a'] + df['b']
100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 ms per loop`

Comment: its the same issue (on windows int32 is the 'default' integer type, so makes some sort of sense, @DSM also reported that on a 32-bit machine); I believe this should fix both